# SSIS 2012 column header is too long for column width Extracting fixed width flat file

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I am attempting to extract a table from sql database into a fixed width flat file.

- The file should have a column header
- I am attempting to recreate a file that already existed where the header for certain columns(for example Gender with a width of 1) has a column name that is too long for it's column format.
- The existing file just cuts off these column headers, so Gender(the db column name and input column to the destination becomes 'G' - just what will fit.. but when I attempt to reproduce the extract in SSIS 2012 by pointing at the existing file while creating the flatFile connectionManager It works without a header, but not when I check "column header in first data row"

Is there a way to change/shorten the column names to just what will fit in the format?  I am using "ragged right" file format and the data looks perfect without column headers.

Any help is appreciated.

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSIS *really* likes consistent metadata. The flat file definition specifies that gender is a length of one and it's going to hold the column header to the same standard that it holds the data. My experience with fixed width files is that they've never had headers, which is painful when they're a few thousand bytes wide, which is likely due to the this problem.

What you can do is to manually specify a header row in the Flat File Destination.

[image]

Within my Connection Manager, I uncheck the Column Names in First Row and increment the Header Rows to Skip value to 1.

[image]

In my example, I used the following query

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
    VALUES
    ('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA','BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB','M','CCCCCCC')
)D(c1, c2, Gender, c4);
```

This results in an output file that looks like

```
Col1Is18BytesWide NextColumnAlignsWithNextGenderSeeWhatIDidThere
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBMCCCCCCC
```

That may or may not be the solution you're looking for. I think it'd drive me mad seeing column headers not aligning with the data values but you never know how other systems expect their data.

Comment: Hi billinkc,  Sorry for the delay in replying - I was busy implementing this solution, which is very simple and solved the problem perfectly!  Your description was concise and easy to follow as well.  thanks again.  Yes this is kind of a silly problem but constraints have me reproducing the exact same files as the old solution...  Oh well.  Thanks again.